# VBScript list installed softwares on windows server 2008 R2

Tags: vbscript, windows-server-2008-r2

I want to list the installed softwares on windows server 2008 R2 with a VBscript. 
I want to verify prerequisite softwares (one of them is .NET Framework 3.5.1).
I actually have two solutions and they both doesn't show all the softwares.

```
Const HKLM = &H80000002 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
installedSoftwaresPath = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\"

Set objReg = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/default:StdRegProv")

objReg.EnumKey HKLM, installedSoftwaresPath, arrSubkeys
For Each strSubkey In arrSubkeys
    Ret = objReg.GetStringValue(HKLM, installedSoftwaresPath & strSubkey, "DisplayName", SoftwareName)
    If Ret <> 0 Then
    objReg.GetStringValue HKLM, strKey & strSubkey, "QuietDisplayName", SoftwareName       
    End If
    If SoftwareName<> "" Then
        WScript.Echo VbCrLf & "Display Name: " & SoftwareName
    End If
Next
```

The other solution is this one :

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colSoftware = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Product")

For Each objSoftware in colSoftware
    WScript.Echo objSoftware.Caption
Next
```

Is it possible to get ALL the installed softwares? if not I'm gonna make a specific solution for every prerequisite softwares.

EDIT :
Some software found by my scripts :

Microsoft Application Error Reporting,
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable,
Microsoft Security Client,
Adobe Reader

What I want to found :
.NET framework 3.5.1

I want a generic solution to found every softwares installed.

SOLUTION :
It seems that there is no generic way to check for installed software. I've found the .NET framework registry key in this path :

```
"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersion\v3.5\"
```

Comment: I guess that those two scripts only show software that is installed by means of Microsoft Windows Installer (MSI). Can you add one or two examples of software that is installed but not showing? That can prove or disprove my hypothesis.

Comment: I edited the question to add the infos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having access to your server to see how the software you're looking for is installed, I can only guess at how you might modify your script.

However, there are other places you should probably be looking besides:
    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\

For example, you may want to look in:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData
```

It's possible that you will find what you are looking for in one of those locations.

You may also want to use RegEdit to do a "Find" for ".NET Framework 3.5.1" to see if that shows up somewhere that you can reliably find it.